# AngularJS store PHP username

Tags: php, angularjs, wordpress

I'm currently developing an AngularJS questionnaire form, which grabs the users username from a WordPress install.

I have successfully managed to receive the users username, but when changing views, then refreshing the browser it looses the username! If I don't refresh the browser the username is visible throughout all the views.

How do I prevent loosing the users username?

**JS**

```
appCtrl.controller('oneCtrl', ['$scope', '$localStorage', '$http', function($scope, $localStorage, $http) {
  $localStorage.$reset();
  $scope.$storage = $localStorage;
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://app.com/user.php',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    username = data;
  }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    alert(data);
  });
}]);

appCtrl.controller('twoCtrl', ['$scope', '$localStorage', function($scope, $localStorage) {
  $scope.username = username;
}]);

appCtrl.controller('threeCtrl', ['$scope', '$localStorage', function($scope, $localStorage) {
  $scope.username = username;
}]);
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
  require_once('/home/app/public_html/wp-load.php' );
  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();
  if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $username = $current_user->user_login;
    echo $username;
  }
?>
```

**Solution**

```
<?php
  $username = $current_user->user_login;
  if($username) {
  echo "<script>var username = '".$username."';</script>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Put it in `sessionStorage` (or `localStorage` if is not so sensitive).

Comment: If is in sessionStorage (better approach), the object will be kept during the session (per browser tab) and will be destroyed when user close it or leave the app like visiting another web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass the username in `<script>var username='<?php echo "tralala";?>';</stript>` on each page(it can be template) and then `username` will be available globaly on your site

Answer (score 0):

1. No need to reset localStorage - just overwrite the value, if necessary.
2. Don't save the value as a global variable - bad practice and leaking data. Instead store it in a service (or worst case - on the $rootScope, though that is a bad practice, as well)
3. Save the username in the local storage, if you want to survive refreshes, but it does leak the data to other users.

My advice, save the username in an angular service (for ease of use) + save the session on the server, so you can query it after the refresh (and store in the service, if there is an existing session).